# RStudio / R: Where does sink() save my file

Tags: r, sink

Im running an analysis in RStudio and use sink to store the output in a file because the line count is too large to manually copy it from the console. The code is:

```
sink("filename.txt")
...analysis
sink()
```

Now, where can I find the filename.txt file on my machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else finds this post I recommend checking where your directory is before your sink statement.

```
getwd()
```

Just in case that is not where you want it to go.

I also keep a default output file destination and set that directory before my sink statement, and redirect after the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it myself, RStudio stores it under My Documents by default.